# Getting RI pin of serial port in C on Windows platform

Tags: c, winapi, serial-port

How to get RI pin status of serial port on a windows platform? I want to read the current state (ON or OFF) , when i get a call on a modem

I can set the DTR pin with :

`EscapeCommFunction(hSerial,SETRTS);`

But cant find an answer online on how to check the RI pin STATUS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [GetCommModemStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcommmodemstatus) function.